# PHP MAILER - Error: The following recipients failed

Tags: php, envio-de-email

```
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];

$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->Host = "smtp.***.com.br";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->Username = 'contato@***.com.br'; 
$mail->Password = '******'; 


$mail->From = $email;  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<ERRO>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
$mail->Sender = "seu@e-mail.com.br"; 
$mail->FromName = "Contato - www.contato.com.br";
```

Quando uso coloco o valor direto no ($mail->From)= "remetente@remetente.com.br". Funciona normalmente, quando coloco uma variável, da erro, algem pode me ajudar?

Comment: Qual erro aparece?

Comment: Poste o erro para podermos ajudar melhor, por gentileza !

Comment: NÃ£o foi possÃ­vel enviar o e-mail. InformaÃ§Ãµes do erro: SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: eduardo@fmaconsulting.com.br
SMTP server error: 5.7.1 : Sender address rejected: Access denied

Comment: Comment this line $mail->IsSMTP();

Answer (score 2):

Você tem que usar assim:

```
$mail->addAddress("destinatario@hotmail.com"); // email do destinatario (para quem a mensagem devera ser enviada).

$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last'); // Aqui define um endereço(email) alternativo para resposta.
```

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei a solução.

Era preciso substituir o método
para:

```
$mail->AddReplyTo($email, $nome);
```

Answer (score -3):

There is aproblem: when sending emails on a loop, if one of the emails is not valid, phpmailer breaks with an exception ans the messages are not sent.

I managed to solve this commenting the lines 1999 to 2008 on PHPMailer.php, as follows:

```
    ***//Create error message for any bad addresses
```

// Removido em 29/10/2021 pois estava quebrando o envio quando encontrava endereços bad
/*        if (count($bad_rcpt) > 0) {
$errstr = '';
foreach ($bad_rcpt as $bad) {
$errstr .= $bad['to'] . ': ' . $bad['error'];
}
throw new Exception($this->lang('recipients_failed') . $errstr, self::STOP_CONTINUE);
}
*/***